# Who kills Julian in Children of Men?

Tags: plot-explanation, children-of-men

It’s implied that the Fishes killed Julian in *Children of Men*, but why?

Also why was Luke so freaked out about her death in the car, when it was seemingly part of the plan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children_of_Men#Plot):

> That night, Theo eavesdrops on a discussion and learns that Julian's death was orchestrated by the Fishes so that Luke could become leader; they intend to kill Theo and use the baby as a political tool to support the coming revolution.

Theo uncovers the scheme when the duo on the motor who shot Julian arrive at the hideout during the night, and he hears this:

> What about all the fucking police, Ian? You said it would be safe!
>
> **We paid the gang.** We had no idea about the cops.
>
> [...]
>
> But we can forget about the baby **if the girl even suspects we killed
>   Julian!**

The behavior of the other people in the car (who were in on the scheme) was obviously not genuine, an act to make Theo and the girl believe in them.

Comment: But the way the scene played out, it didn’t feel like it. It feels inconsistent with the emotions the charecters were going through, with Luke visibly upset and surprised about her death